# I can't change my theme on prestashop

Tags: themes, prestashop, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-1.7

There's a theme selected but whenever I click on "activate theme" or something like that, it loads for a while and says that the theme had been successfully installed but afterwards, it didn't change a bit.

I'm maybe guessing it has something to do with the cache but I'm not sure.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Go to the config folder of your new theme
- Edit the theme.yml file
- Change the value of name and display_name (2 first attributes) with the name of your theme. (lowcase)

Tell me if it's good.